# Как открыть изображение в виджете Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Я хочу открыть png изображение из файла в виджете. На форуме нашёл как открыть изображение с помощью Qpixmap и QLabel, но изображение открывается отдельным окном, а мне хочется открыть его в виджете. Покопавшись в виджетах, я нашёл "Graphics view", но так и не понял как его использовать.
Я пытался читать документацию, но так и не нашёл там ответа (возможно плохо искал, возможно
не понял из-за своих скудных знаний английского). 
Система Mac OS 10.15.3
Использую Qt Creator
Пожалуйста не бейте палками за простой вопрос, ибо я совсем новичок.
Надеюсь на помощь
Как я открываю изображение в окне:

```
QLabel label; 
QPixmap myPixmap( "/Users/justtomu/Documents/test.png" ); 
label.setPixmap( myPixmap ); 
label.show();
```

[image: в этом белом квадратике должна быть картинка]

Comment: ну нарисуйте в дизайнере виджет с QLabel и в неё вставьте QPixmap, а у вас похоже, что QLabel не имея родителя появляется на десктопе.

Comment: если путь правильный, то должно отображать если QLabel объявлен в main, если метка объявляется в каком-либо методе любого окна/виджета, то она удаляется сразу по завершении работы этого метода

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. Может кому-нибудь понадобится. В файле `mainwindow.cpp` в классе mainwindow нужно добавить

```
image.load("/Users/justtomu/Documents/test.png");
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
scene->addPixmap(image);
scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());
ui->mainImage->setScene(scene);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent=nullptr) :QMainWindow(parent) {
        centralWidget()->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());

        QLabel* label = new QLabel("");
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap("/Users/justtomu/Documents/test.png"));

        centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(label);
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(...) {
    QApplication a(...);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение, конечно, рабочее, но это из танка по воробьям) Потому как сцена и её вьюха - это все-таки инструменты для работы с некоторой, но все же графикой.
В этом же случае будет правильней отнаследовать QWidget и переопределить ему *paintEvent*

Comment: а наследование paintEvent это уже по воробьям атомной бомбой